# Replace values per sign (+/-) in a column

Tags: awk

I am trying to build a .bed file with genome coordinates and I am pretty close. Just missing the final step.
I have a file that looks like this:

```
LQNS02278165.1  13104710        13109495        BEL-1_PH-I      4785
LQNS02278165.1  9139127         9142308         BEL-1_PH-I      3181
LQNS02278165.1  9222957         9221339         BEL-1_PH-I      -1618
```

I need to replace the 5 column with the sign, with is gonna be the orientation in the genome.
ideally the output looks like this:

```
LQNS02278165.1  13104710        13109495        BEL-1_PH-I      +
LQNS02278165.1  9139127         9142308         BEL-1_PH-I      +
LQNS02278165.1  9222957         9221339         BEL-1_PH-I      -
```

Any suggestion with awk will be very appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
awk '{$NF=($NF<0 ? "-" : "+")}1' file
```

- `$NF=($NF<0 ? "-" : "+")` If last field is negative, replace it with a minus sign, else replace it with a plus sign.
- `1` prints the line.

Answer (score 0):

commad

```
awk '{if ($NF ~ "-"){$NF="-";print }else{$NF="+";print }}' filename
```

output

```
LQNS02278165.1 13104710 13109495 BEL-1_PH-I +
LQNS02278165.1 9139127 9142308 BEL-1_PH-I +
LQNS02278165.1 9222957 9221339 BEL-1_PH-I -
```